# How to use position_dodge with 2 levels of groupings in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, grouping, r-forestplot

I would like to group a series of lines by 2 factors using group = interaction in ggplot. Here is some sample code:

```
set.seed(123)
N <- 18
means <- rnorm(N,0,1)
ses <- rexp(N,2)
upper<- means+qnorm(0.975)*ses
lower<- means+qnorm(0.025)*ses
fruit <- rep(c("Apples","Bananas","Pears"), each=6)
size <- rep(rep(c("Small","Medium","Big"), each=2),3)
GMO <- rep(c("Yes","No"), 9)
d<- data.frame(means,upper,lower,fruit,size,GMO)


ggplot(data=d,
       aes(x = fruit,y = means, ymin = lower, ymax = upper, col=size,linetype=GMO,group=interaction(GMO, size)))+
  geom_hline(aes(fill=size),yintercept =1, linetype=2)+
  xlab('labels')+ ylab("Parameter estimates (95% Confidence Interval)")+
  geom_pointrange(position=position_dodge(width = 0.6)) +
  scale_x_discrete(name="Fruits")+
  coord_flip()-> fplot
dev.new()
fplot
```

Here's a link to the resulting graph: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YF4F.png

I would like to bring the same coloured lines for each of the three groups closer together. In other words I would like the lines to cluster not only by the 'Fruit' variable but also the 'Size' variable for each of the fruits. poisition_dodge seems to only work for one of the interacting groups.

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know that is not possible with `position_dodge`, i.e. it dodges according to the categories of the `group` aes. And it does not matter whether you map one variable on the group aes or an interaction of two or more. The groups are simply placed equidistant from one another.

One option to achieve your desired result would be to use the "facets that don't look like facets" trick which means faceting by `fruit`, mapping `size` on `x` and afterwards using `theme` options to get rid of the facet look plus some tweaking of the `x` scale:

```r
set.seed(123)
N <- 18
means <- rnorm(N, 0, 1)
ses <- rexp(N, 2)
upper <- means + qnorm(0.975) * ses
lower <- means + qnorm(0.025) * ses
fruit <- rep(c("Apples", "Bananas", "Pears"), each = 6)
size <- rep(rep(c("Small", "Medium", "Big"), each = 2), 3)
GMO <- rep(c("Yes", "No"), 9)
d <- data.frame(means, upper, lower, fruit, size, GMO)


library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = d, aes(x = size, y = means, ymin = lower, ymax = upper, col = size, linetype = GMO, group = GMO)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1, linetype = 2) +
  xlab("labels") +
  ylab("Parameter estimates (95% Confidence Interval)") +
  geom_pointrange(position = position_dodge(width = 0.6)) +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "Fruits", breaks = "Medium", labels = NULL, expand = c(0, 1)) +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_grid(fruit ~ ., switch = "y") +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside", 
        strip.background.y = element_blank(),
        strip.text.y.left = element_text(angle = 0),
        panel.spacing.y = unit(0, "pt"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to `facet_wrap` your size variable:

```r
set.seed(123)
N <- 18
means <- rnorm(N,0,1)
ses <- rexp(N,2)
upper<- means+qnorm(0.975)*ses
lower<- means+qnorm(0.025)*ses
fruit <- rep(c("Apples","Bananas","Pears"), each=6)
size <- rep(rep(c("Small","Medium","Big"), each=2),3)
GMO <- rep(c("Yes","No"), 9)
d<- data.frame(means,upper,lower,fruit,size,GMO)

library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.1.2
ggplot(data=d,
       aes(x = fruit,y = means, ymin = lower, ymax = upper, col=size,linetype=GMO,group=interaction(GMO, size)))+
  geom_hline(aes(fill=size),yintercept =1, linetype=2)+
  xlab('labels')+ ylab("Parameter estimates (95% Confidence Interval)")+
  geom_pointrange(position=position_dodge(width = 0.6)) +
  scale_x_discrete(name="Fruits")+
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(~size)-> fplot
#> Warning: geom_hline(): Ignoring `mapping` because `yintercept` was provided.
fplot
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This doesn't actually do what I had in mind but could work as a solution. Thanks.